# Some questions about d3js.symbol

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to plot values using different symbols, and here's my code:

```
            var mCircle = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(8);
            var mCross= d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross).size(8);
            svg.selectAll(".dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("path")
                
                .attr("transform", function (d) { console.log(data);return "translate(" + scatterXScale(d.x) + "," + scatterYScale(d.y) + ")"})
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    if (modelPredictions[id = d.id] == '0') {
                        return mCircle;
                    } else {
                        return mCross;
                    }
                })
```

Where modelPredictions will contain 0's and 1's. However, I get the error like`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm')`. Do you have any idea abou this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Just call the function: `var mCircle = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(8)();` and `var mCross= d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross).size(8)();`. Look at the `()` at the end.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks! That's amazing! Do you mind telling more about why it works this way? Many thanks!

Comment: Because it's a function, it needs to be called.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried to use  `var mCircle = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(8)` and `.attr("d", mCircle)`, it can also draw circles on the plot... Do you mean actually mCircle can be defined as a function?

Comment: It is a function. When you do `.attr("d", mCircle)` it's automatically called (`selection.attr` does that).